# Regex: match digits-digits_digits-digits

Tags: php, regex

**I want to match**

```
123-123
or
123-123_123-123
```

**I do not want to match**

```
123_123
or
123-123 not underscore 123-123
or
123--123
```

**I tried**

```
(\d+)-(\d+)
```

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com ... regex is hard, it always takes me some trial and error. This debuggex tool really helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
/^(?:(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)-(\d+))$|^(?:(\d+)-(\d+))$/
```

Working example based on your input here: https://regex101.com/r/1GOOzQ/2